# lettuce\salad\splinter django testing seems to delete all data from production database - this is bug or feature?

Tags: database, django, testing

string from postgresql log:

> TRUNCATE "blog_post", "django_admin_log", "auth_permission", "auth_group", "auth_group_permissions", "django_session", "auth_user_groups", "south_migrationhistory", "auth_user_user_permissions", "blog_tag", "blog_post_tag", "django_site", "auth_user", "django_content_type";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that i understood the reason. Letucce using 'default' django database by default, and salad resets the database before running each scenario.